# Setting the dojoConfig variable for finding my .js file

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have two projects (first one works great and I thought I had learned something)  However, in the second project I am unable to load the .js file 'ParcelQuery.js'

My project is not using the http://localhost:/js/gis/dijit/ParcelQuery.js (like I thought it would).

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://js.arcgis.com/3.14compact/js/gis/dijit/ParcelQuery.js"

```
var dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        packages: [{
            name: "dijit", 
            //this regex type expression takes you directly to the location 'relative path'
            location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]*$/, '') + 'js/gis/dijit'               
        }]
    };
```

the .js file lives in a folder here in the project.  I'm looking to load the 'ParcelQuery.js'

[image: shows the variable and the section of the project tree]

Answer (score 0):

If I had not asked this, ... uggh..

ok, the answer is this I have already loaded the .js file and was calling it incorrectly.

```
 var dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        packages: [{
            name: 'viewer',
            location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '') + 'js/viewer'
        }, {
            name: 'config',
            location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '') + 'js/config'
        }, {
            name: 'gis',
            location: location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '') + 'js/gis'
        }           
    ]
```

the ParcelQuery.js file lives inside the 'js/gis/dijit/' folder.  My call to load it in the AMD loader  should be like this

```
'gis/dijit/ParcelQuery',
```

Comment: the ```location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '')``` is probably not necessary as you can use relative path: ```../```